# Apollo-Angular query return weird behaviour

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-angular

I am trying to connect Angular with a GraphQL backend.

However, when angular-apollo requests data from GraphQL, the data is being sent correctly but when I want to access it, it returns `undefined`.

In the following code, `updateItems()` is working correctly but `getItems()` not.

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const GET_ITEMS = gql`
  { 
    items(limit: 1) {
      name
      rank
    }
  }
`;

const GET_ITEM = gql`
query Item($name: String!) {
  item(name: $name) {
    currency
    history {
      timestamp
      price
      volume
    }
  }
}
`;

type ItemType = {
    name: string,
    rank: number
}

type ItemhistoryType = {
    name: string,
    currency: string,
    history: {
        timestamp: number,
        price: number,
        volume: number
    }[]
}

type Query = {
  items: ItemType[];
}

type ItemQuery = {
  itemhistory: ItemhistoryType;
}

@Injectable()
export class ItemsService {
  items: ItemType[] = [];
  itemStatus = new EventEmitter<ItemType[]>();
  itemhistories: ItemhistoryType[] = [];
  itemhistoryStatus = new EventEmitter<ItemhistoryType>();

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {
    this.updateItems();
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items.slice();
  }

  updateItems() {
    this.apollo.query<Query>({
      query: GET_ITEMS
    }).subscribe(result => {
      this.items = result.data.items as ItemType[];
      console.log(this.items);
      this.itemStatus.emit(this.items.slice());
    });
  }

  getItem(name: string) {
    console.log(name);
    this.apollo.query<ItemQuery>({
      query: GET_ITEM, 
      variables: { name: name }
    }).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result.data); // shows data correctly
      let itemhistory = result.data.itemhistory as ItemhistoryType;
      console.log(itemhistory); // -> undefined
    });
  }
}
```

In `getItem(name)`, the `console.log(result.data)` call shows this in the console:

```
{item: {…}}
  item:
    currency: "€"
    history: (2287) [{…}, …]
    __typename: "Itemhistory"
    __proto__: Object
  __proto__: Object
```

which is correct but when I try to log `itemhistory` it shows `undefined`.
Also I can't access `result.data.item` because it does not exist.

Does anyone know what the problem is? I am thankful for every answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue but the solution is not perfect.
Instead of `result.data.item` I need to call `result?.data?.item`.

The new method is:

```
getItem(name: string) {
    this.apollo.query({
      query: GET_ITEM,
      variables: {
        name: name
      }
    })
      .subscribe((result: any) => {
        const history = result?.data?.item as ItemhistoryType;
        this.itemhistories.push(history);
        this.itemhistoryStatus.emit(history);
      })
}
```